# Can I stop crop dusters repeatedly flying over my home?

Tags: faa-regulations, noise, aerial-application

I have a crop-duster spraying the fields around me often. He flies over my house no matter what field he is spraying every few minutes. I think he uses my house as a pivot point. The old pilot rarely flew over my place.

My livestock goes nuts. It is annoying. He has to fly low and is loud. I called the company  awhile back and they said he was new and he would talk to him. He is back today flying over repeatedly and I called the company and the owner told me he would call me back. No call back and it goes to voice mail now when I call him.

Is there anything I can do? I told the owner that I understood they may have to fly over once in awhile but this is over the top.

Comment: related, if not duplicate: https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/8391/1467 (question is tagged EASA, but answers include the US)

Comment: [Also related](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/37866/1696), good info about reporting so the FAA can investigate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the flight rules for crop dusters?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/8201/what-are-the-flight-rules-for-crop-dusters)

Comment: @fooot  The answer to "what are the rules for cropdusters" doesn't answer the question what an individual can DO in the case of rules being violated. That question is clearly related, but not really a duplicate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are seaplanes allowed to taxi in residential areas?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/37866/are-seaplanes-allowed-to-taxi-in-residential-areas)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barrage_balloon

Comment: "over the top". Good one.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S-400_missile_system

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nike_Hercules

Answer (score 45):

In a rural area pilots can fly pretty low, and are permitted to fly even lower while carrying out a lawful activity such as crop-dusting. Even if the pilot flew at 500 feet above your house, which is probably the maximum that he needs to stay away, it would still be loud and disturbing to your livestock.

You should try to work it out with the company and/or the pilot in an amicable way.

Unless your house is located in a congested area, the minimum altitude the pilot must maintain is 500 ft. However, if your house is located in a sparsely populated area, the pilot may be able to fly much lower than that. However, while the pilot is in the process of spraying, or turning around to spray he is allowed to fly lower than that minimum. Otherwise, the pilot may have to do dangerous steep climbs and descents.

For example, lets say the pilot is in violation of minimum altitude regulations by flying over your house at some minimal altitude below 500 ft. Lets assume you get the pilot busted and the pilot receives a warning, citation, or temporary suspension. When he comes back he can just fly over at 500 ft legally all day long, and that will probably be almost as noisy and disturbing to your livestock.

Alternatively, you can lease a small part of your land to AT&T to put a 1000ft tall cellular antenna on your property.

But seriously, as a pilot, if I heard that my flying was causing you so many problems, I would try to avoid it as best as possible, so long as it doesn't affect safety.

Comment: Could you lawfully build such a tower yourself? I assume even a 300 ft mast, which is probably doable, would be enough to scare pilots away. Or, easier, fly kites? (Of course a mast could be an even more valuable landmark...)

Comment: After some googling it looks as if radio masts are (locally?) regulated, e.g. see https://library.municode.com/tx/rowlett/codes/code_of_ordinances?nodeId=PTIICOOR_CH62TE_ARTIIANMATO. Not sure whether a reason can be conjured up for a 300ft or so mast, and it would need a permit and cost an inspection. Not sure about "non-purpose" edifices ("it's my new hobby"); the mentioned regulation appears to specifically concern radio antennas. There are likely building and safety codes etc., but in a rural area they may be pretty lenient.

Comment: @Devil07, what is your basis for suggesting a violation of minimum altitude regulations by flying over [a] house at 200 ft?

Comment: I like the tower idea. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barrage_balloon

Comment: I think the kite idea is much more practical. It is cheap, easy to setup, and is not regulated.

Comment: @mongo it was just offered as an example; it may or may not be a violation. If pilot needs to fly at 200ft over OP's house to safely conduct his crop dusting or for landing and take-offs, then its likely not a violation. But, if he is just flying over her house as a reference point all day at 200ft, then he might be violating FAR 91.119 (c), which requires aircraft to fly at 500 feet  above the surface in "other than congested areas" or at distance of 500 feet from any person (i.e. the OP), vessel, vehicle (i.e the OP's tractor), or structure (i.e. barn), in a "sparsely populated" area.

Comment: Where's the ATT tower comment?

Comment: Actually, for the most parts, radio masts are regulated federally by the FCC. As a ham radio operator, you can build a properly licensed station and could have a 1000 ft tower. You would have to clear it with the FAA if you are near an airport, add lights etc as required, and the locals have a say as far as safety goes, but nothing else (again, as long as it is somehow properly licensed by the FCC). So the locals could dictate where it goes on your property so it could not fall on other people's property, but that's about it.

Comment: @Devil07, Your wording suggests that 200 ft might be some threshold for violation of unsafe altitude, which for 14 CFR 137 operations, it is not.

Comment: @mongo I tried to make it clear that the 200 ft was a hypothetical by starting the clause with the phrase "lets say that...." Also, it says 200 ft instead of 500 ft (the assumption is that 500 ft is the threshold).  14CFR137 only modifies the part 91 minimum altitudes for "congested areas." And even in congested areas the aircraft can only deviate from part 91 minimums as required "for the proper accomplishment of the agricultural aircraft operations." Thank you for the input, I will try to update and revise so it is more clear.

Comment: A series of mega wind turbines along the perimeter of OP's property would be more effective and much more profitable. Vestas V164 produces 8MW each and is 722ft tall.

Comment: @Davil07, the facts disagree with your statement that 14CFR137 only modified the part 91 minimum altitudes for "congested areas." I refer you to 14CFR137.49, titled Operations over other than congested areas, and states in part, "an aircraft may be operated over other than congested areas below 500 feet above the surface and closer than 500 feet to persons, vessels, vehicles, and structures..."  That is clearly different than the verbiage in 14CFR91.119.

Comment: @mongo You are technically correct, which is the best kind of correct! Part 91 allows a pilot to go below those minimums only for landing and takeoffs, but 137.49 includes "during the actual dispensing operation" and approaches, departures and turnarounds reasonably necessary for operation." I'll incorporate into answer.

Comment: Your first sentence sounds a bit as if pilots are required to use higher altitudes when performing unlawful activities ... :)

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen  I adjusted the sentence for you. I left "lawful" in there because I wanted to make the point that there isn't anything improper with crop dusting.

Comment: The FAA has no authority over structures i.e. buildings and towers. They make recommendations and give advice but local government has the ultimate authority. The FAA will often tie funding of airports to their regulatory wishes - but only on airport property.

Comment: @Devil07 Other than the poison they are spraying on your food :)

Comment: @Cloud: And on you, if they're spraying crops near where you live.

Answer (score 41):

I did some Pawnee flying years ago, and have fielded a bunch of complaints about ag applicators from people.  Here's my experience:

1. The [FSDO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flight_Standards_District_Office) will probably not care.  Ag application is a different set of rules, and there is wide latitude on min safe alt.  You can talk to them, but in my experience, they yawn.
2. New guys aren't always sensitive to the community.
3. Personal visits, and if you can nicely talking with the pilot almost always works, but certainly talking with the boss works.
4. In the states I am most familiar with, there are right to farm legislation, and that makes life easier for farmers (and ag applicators).
5. Contacting the farmer who is working the land, and having him get you in touch with the applicator is also a good strategy, because farmers care more about their neighbors than applicators.

Having said all that, if you are having livestock issues, then you are being harmed, and there is greater risk. Personally, I would write a letter and send it to the farmer, applicator (if you know who) and the FSDO. Ultimately, in my experience, these matters are resolved only by persuading the applicator to do his field differently.

Sorry, no regurgitation of regulations here, because from your description, the regulations are not going to fix things.

Addendum #1 
I changed my mind.  I need to cite 14 CFR 137.49, which states that an aircraft may be operated closer than 500 feet to persons, buildings and the ground.  This is essential for effective ag application, and I can say that 50 foot clearances over buildings are quite common.  100 foot clearances over houses are as well.  How low is too low?  Where will you go when the fan quits, and if you can clear the structure or person and make a suitable off airport landing (or at least argue that you could) then you are fine. The rules are different for congested areas, and the FAA changes their interpretation of congested areas as they wish, but in all my years in aviation, I have never heard of a ag applicator being violated for unsafe altitude, when performing ag operations. So to summarize, over an uncongested area, there is no regulatory figure of X number of feet.  It's not 500, it's not 200. Period.

Finally, if you are aggrieved by the operation, then you may have a tort action, not a regulatory action. In all fairness, there have been successful tort actions where disturbance of livestock and race horses have been involved.

Comment: "Where will you go when the fan quits" reminds me of the old joke that the prop is there to keep the pilot cool. Just see him sweat when it stops...

Answer (score 12):

Crop dusting is a legitimate reason to be flying low, so the FAA is almost certainly not going to come to your aid. From their point of view what he's doing is legal, as long as he isn't doing something unsafe.

Obviously you should try every recourse to resolve it amicably. But if you need to involve law enforcement it will be your local sheriff that would deal with things like annoyances and such. Since you have cattle I'm assuming you're not inside a city limit, so it's possible there are no noise ordinances that he's violating. You may have little recourse, legally.

It sounds a little screwy to me. The dusters I've watched never spend more than an hour or so even on large fields. There may be something about the topography or transmission wires or something that makes your place a good spot to turn or something. If you think he might be intentionally harassing you since you called his company that would be something local law enforcement would be responsible for. The FAA would almost certainly tell you to call the local police/sheriff.

Comment: There are several fields that surround me that he sprays.  He goes back to his base and refills and comes back.   I have 800ft in front of my house and 1,200 behind it plus several hundred acres all around that he could use to turn without buzzing me repeatedly.   I think he just uses my place as  a pivot point.

Answer (score 8):

Preface: I am not an aviation lawyer and the advice I offer here should not be interpreted as the letter of the law. A real lawyer may be necessary in some instances.

The other answers here cover the regulations well, but as for a course of action, if you feel he is breaching a regulation (flying dangerously low for no reason etc.) you can reach out to your [local FSDO](https://www.faa.gov/about/office_org/field_offices/fsdo/) to report it.

> **Contact a FSDO for**
>
> - Low-flying aircraft

However as mentioned they may not be of much help since he is more than likely well within his rights as they pertain to the FAA.

The other option you have is to speak with your local legislators about a [noise abatement for the area](https://www.faa.gov/about/office_org/headquarters_offices/apl/noise_emissions/airport_aircraft_noise_issues/) which you may have some very legitimate grounds for.